# wordpress options page update meta date on submit

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to make a plugin, that prints all posts of type attachment, and enables quick edit of their title and alt text.

I know how to print the posts with get_posts, and I know how to update the alt text with update_post_meta.

The problem I am having is running update_post_meta on a form submission in an admin options page. All I can find is how to submit settings.

So what I need to know is how to execute some code on submit.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'plugin_create_menu');

function plugin_create_menu() {
    add_menu_page('My Cool Plugin Settings', 'Cool Settings', 'administrator', __FILE__, 'plugin_settings_page') );
}

function plugin_settings_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Plugin</h2>

        <form method="post" action="options.php">


            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Please share the code you've written so far.

Comment: I didnt paste my code because I found it irrelevent, since my issue is not related to my code, but to how wordpress handles form submission.